# Alias External Module in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on a project where I want to package my source in to multiple modules (in different files). I do this so I can include only certain pieces on certain pages to reduce the overall weight.

The problem I'm having is I can't figure out a syntax which will let me alias the external modules, and I really don't want to have to write out the full module every time (since it's usually something like A.B.C.D for organization).

When I compile, I have a script which grabs all the files, so I have the external definition file as the first parameter.

If I write out the whole module `(A.B.C.D.MyClass)`, it recognizes that. If I try to do:

```
module MyModule {
    import ABCD = A.B.C.D;

    export MyClass {
        //...
        public myFunc(obj:ABCD.MyClass) {}
    }
}
```

It'll tell me that `'The name "ABCD" does not exist in the current scope."'`

If it matters, I export all of my classes, but don't export any modules. I generate the definition file which is included (so the definition file which contains A.B.C.D is first in my list when I compile).

Any ideas?

## Update

To elaborate on my file structure, I have something like this:

- A

  - B

    - a.ts
    - b.ts
  - C

    - c.ts
    - d.ts

And then elsewhere I may also have:

- A

  - D

    - e.ts
    - f.ts
    - E

      - g.ts
      - h.ts

In this case, I would build the first set into something like A.B.ts by compiling them with something like:

```
tsc A/B/a.ts A/B/b.ts A/B/C/c.ts A/B/C/d.ts --out A.B.ts --declarations
```

Then, when I go to package the next I would do something like:

```
tsc /path/to/A.B.d.ts A/D/e.ts A/D/f.ts A/D/E/g.ts A/D/E/h.ts --out A.D.ts --declarations
```

I build those compiler commands dynamically by recursing through a set of files I specify so it gets those compiler things.

Comment: Can you please describe your file structure and the export definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are packaging your modules in multiple files in order to load them using the AMD module loading pattern, you need to do the following...

The name of the file is the module name, you don't add `module` declarations

For example...

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass {
    }
}
```

Should actually be `MyModule.ts` and look like this:

```
export class MyClass {
}
```

You would then load it using:

```
import my = module('MyModule');
```

I think you are currently trying to mix a bundling style of TypeScript code with a module style of loading, which is incompatible. When you are bundling, the file-names don't matter as you take the responsibility for getting the scripts on the page. When you are using AMD or CommonJS, you need to abide by the file naming rules (i.e. file-name equals module name) and leave out the enclosing `module`.

As a side note, there is a bug in 0.8.1.1 that affects this, so you may want to read through this if you are on 0.8.1.1: http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/405800

Comment: I have submodules that I use too. In my case, if the module is A.B.C.D with the main module being A.B they all use, should I call the file A.B.ts and just have module C.D in the file, or is there some other way?

Comment: If you want a hierarchical module structure, you would normally create a folder structure and have `A/B/C/D.ts`, which you could load using `import abcd = module('./A/B/C/D');`

Comment: So, I'm creating larger modules which I then want compressed in to files which I can then serve up. If each class is in it's own file, that is WAY too many files to be serving. I'm trying to do something like about 50 classes (each in it's own file) to about 4 JS files.

Comment: I would aim for one file per module, until that becomes too unwieldy, rather than one file per class.

Comment: I also have my TypeScript project as one class per file. I then use GruntJS, and have my grunt file concatenate the files into one, wrap in module patterns (when project file is going to be used in browser), jslint it, unit test it, and on success, minify it, and then copy the non minified and minified version of the single file to a distribution folder.  I use Visual Studio, so I have my grunt command triggered on build of the project.

Comment: @AlexKlock bundling is also an option in ASP.NET MVC. Having one class per file doesn't really cut it for CommonJS or AMD without a bit of shimming things about though.

Comment: Thanks Alex. This is a very large JavaScript project for a web application with a team of multiple people. Having one file per module is not an acceptable development pattern. That would require way too many manual merges, etc. to be efficient, not to mention the general issues with having that much code in a single file.