# Typescript : Alias a long module name

Tags: typescript

I looked this up already, going to the following questions:

#### [Alias External Module in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851990/alias-external-module-in-typescript)

#### [Type reference without full namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541843/type-reference-without-full-namespace)

But I am still confused. This is not a "requirement", just a desire. I am using `Kendo UI` and their MVVM architecture in Typescript, and I find myself constantly typing this out ...

```
class Item extends ItemPrototype {
   public Quality: kendo.data.ObservableObject = new kendo.data.ObservableObject();
}
```

Yeah, that works fine, but it is getting obnoxious. Is there a way I can set up typescript to let me use a short hand? Like ...

```
class Item extends ItemPrototype {
   public Quality: observable = new observable();
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes there is a way.  `import` can be used to import a module or also to define a type name to make it shorter.  Here's an example of the latter:

```
declare module alpha.bravo.charlie {
    export class Delta {
        constructor();
    }
}

import Delta = alpha.bravo.charlie.Delta;
let d: Delta = new Delta();
```

You can also save typing by letting the type inference system do some of the work.

```
let d = new Delta();
```

More info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases

Comment: word of caution: when using an external source that dynamically loads .js , you may have a timing issue, and your import may fail if the (type) .js for what you are aliasing isn't d/l yet.  I wish I could invoke an import in a callback for this atypical case. Happened to me with bing maps v8.

Answer (score 2):

From 1.4 we have ability to use `type` keyword.

> With TypeScript 1.3 out the door, we're focused on adding more type
>   system and ECMAScript 6 features to TypeScript. Let's take a quick
>   look at some of the new features you'll be able to use in the next
>   release of TypeScript. All these features are live in the master
>   branch on our GitHub repository if you'd like to check them out
>   yourself today.
>
> With these features, we can more accurately and easily work with
>   variables and expressions that may have different types at runtime.
>   Together, these features help reduce the need for explicit type
>   annotations, type assertions, and use of the 'any' type. Type
>   definition file (.d.ts) authors can use these to more precisely
>   describe external libraries. For those following the development of
>   the compiler, you'll notice we're already using these features in the
>   compiler today.

For more information, please visit: [TypeScript 1.4 sneak peek: union types, type guards, and more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx)

Example:

Let's to create simple model: basemodel.ts

```
module NameSpace {
    export module Model {
        export class BaseModel {
            public Id: number;
            public Name: string;
        }
    }
}
```

and we need to use this model in our controller.

```
/// <reference path="path to base model.ts" />

type BaseModel = NameSpace.Model.BaseModel;

module NameSpace {
    export module Controller {
        export class BaseController  {
            public entities: new Array<BaseModel>();

            constructor(externalEntities: Array<BaseModel>) {
                this.entities = externalEntities;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Type aliases do not work for the question's example since they only introduce a new name for the type, not it's constructor (`const Quality: observable` would work, `const quality = new observable()` would not)

Comment: Hello could share example with source (gist, etc.) ?

Comment: Scroll to the top, have a look at the example given in the question and try to shorten the expression `new kendo.data.ObservableObject()` using type aliases. You will find that it's impossible since the constructor in the expression is a function and type aliases do not introduce a new name for values (such as functions), only for types. In your example, the error would be at `new BaseModel()` in the second snippet

Comment: Please visit: https://gist.github.com/dimitardanailov/c2ab460743a72a5ed457. Implementation between Angularjs 1.4 and Typescript.

Comment: See line 78 in your sample: `const tempButton: SubmitButton = new Myteletouch.Entity.DOM.FormElement.SubmitButton.SubmitButton(`. It cannot be shortened with `type` aliases alone. I feel like I'm talking with a wall.

Comment: Yes I know and I can't understand why something is working, something you need to add full path. 

Example `private ApplicationUserShippingAddressDatabaseService: IApplicationUserShippingAddressDatabaseService`.

Comment: If you do not understand the concept, then why do you post it as an answer? Here's a gist which outlines why using `type` is not adequate for this use case: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a05e935fb16cd29da657